# Measure of Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I consider $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb N} \in L^p(\mu)$ and $\vert|f_n-f\vert|_p \rightarrow 0 $ for $ n \rightarrow \infty$

So I can conclude: Let $ \epsilon_k =2^{-k}$

$ \forall k  \ \exists n_k: \mu(\{|f_n -f_m|>\epsilon_k \}) \leq \epsilon_k \ \forall m,n \geq n_k $

Because of the $L^p$ convergence the set has to be a null set.

I cannot imagine how you can state that in a mathematical way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu (|f_n-f_m| > \epsilon_k) \leq \frac 1 {\epsilon_k^{p}} \int |f_n-f_m|^{p} < \epsilon_k$ if $\int |f_n-f_m|^{p} <\epsilon_k^{p+1}$ and this is true for $n$ and $m$ are sufficiently large. So the answer is YES. [ Note that $\int |f_n-f_m|^{p} \to 0$ because $|f_n-f_m|^{p} \leq 2^{p} (|f_n-f|^{p}+|f-f_m|^{p})$].

Comment: How do you conclude: $\mu (|f_n-f_m| > \epsilon_k) \leq \frac 1 {\epsilon_k^{p}} \int |f_n-f_m|^{p} $ By definition is $ \mu(|f_n-f_m|) = \int |f_n-f_m| d \mu$ What can I do with $> \epsilon_k$

Comment: This is a standard arguemnt. $\int |f_n-f_m|^{p} \geq \int_{\{|f_n-f_m| >\epsilon_k\}} |f_n-f_m|^{p} \geq \epsilon_k^{p} \mu(\{|f_n-f_m| >\epsilon_k\})$.

Comment: For the first inequality you are using monotonicity of Lebesgue integration, Why is $\mu (|f_n-f_m| > \epsilon_k) \epsilon_k^{p} \leq  \int_{|f_n-f_m|>\epsilon_k} |f_n-f_m|^{p} $

Comment: $\int_A g d \mu \geq c\mu(A)$ if  $g \geq c$ on $A$. To see this note that $I_A(g-c I_A)$ is a non-negative measurable function, so its integral is $\geq 0$.

Comment: I don't understand that. How is $ \epsilon_k^p$ compensated?